# C passing argument 1 of ‘fread’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c

I'm sorry to bother you with this, but i'm stuck with it for too long already.
I get the following warning on fread: "warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fread’ makes pointer from integer without a cast"
I'm new to C and really like it, but don't get over this.
Thanks in advance.

```
    typedef unsigned char byte;

    int main( int argc, char *argv[]){
        FILE * filein;
        filein = fopen(argv[1], "r" );
        int width=10;
        int height=10;
        byte ** data;

        // Allocation
        data = (byte **) malloc(height*sizeof(byte *));
        for(int i=0;i<height;i++){
            data[i]=(byte *) malloc(width*sizeof(byte));
        }

        for(int i=0;i<height;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<width;j++){
                fread(data[i][j], sizeof(const char), 1, infile);
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<height;i++){
            free(data[i]);
        }
        free(data);
        fclose(filein);

        return 0;
        exit(0);
    }
```

This is only a small piece of the actual program. The task is to read a binary pgm-image, store it in a data-matrix, normalize the values and write them to a new binary pgm-image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

fread() expects the void* pointer to the buffer. You are passing the *value* stored in data[i][j], not the *pointer* to the element data[i][j].

Try using the

```
fread(&data[i][j], sizeof(const char), 1, infile);
```

By the way, .pgm file format ([if this is it](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html)) has a header and it is not sufficient to read only the width*height characters. The pixel values are also separated by spaces, so a little parsing is required. Also keep in mind that the end-of-line symbols also take space (.pgm cannot have more than 70 characters on one line)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped. The header parsing and everything else works aready. I've only posted the parts of code that where relevant to the problem for less confusion, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The type of data[i][j] is byte. That is not a pointer.  What you really want is to read to &data[i][j], if you're reading one byte at a time.

Answer (score 0):

To read a single char, you can do

```
int c; // not char, because it must be able to hold EOF
c = getc(infile);
if( c == EOF ){
   // do something about error or premature EOF
}
data[i][j] = c;
```

This is more verbose mostly because of the error checking that your code doesn't do.